# Labview Saving multiple segments into one file

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, save, labview

[image]

I am converting an SDK vi provided by a data acquisition card company to suit my needs. The original vi records multiple data segments in the card memory and displays in a waveform graph on the front panel without any saving to file function. I can input "Number of Records" to set how many segments (waveforms) I want to acquire. Once the acquisition is over, I can click on "segment" (a "control" on the front panel to input a number) to view the nth segment. To save all the data segments into one file, I put the "Write Delimited Spreadsheet VI" in this VI, with attache to file and transpose function.

My problem is that once I add the save file function, the VI is only saving one segment if the "Run" is set at "False," and then by clicking the arrow to add one in the "Segment" control on the front panel, the next segment data will be saved in the same file and attach after the previously segment. Or the VI will keep saving data without stopping if the "Run" is set at "True. What I want is when I set the "Number of Records" as X (an integer), the file will save X segments. I tried to add a counter to automatically add one each time and replace the "Segment" input but was not working.

I feel that I am getting very close to what I want but after a week I decided to ask for help. Any comments and suggestions welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. A counter is needed. Add it to shift register of the While Loop (not the For Loop!).
2. Add saving of data to the While Loop (move it out from For Loop).
3. Increase counter (in the While Loop), and save data until the counter reaches Segment’s value.

Let me also give one recommendation: try to change current implementation to some more flexible design pattern (such as State Machine or Producer-Consumer). Currently, your code is quite messy, coupled, etc. - so it could be a challenge to debug it or to add new features. Both of the patterns mentioned can be explored more by looking at the Project Templates (available when you create a new project).

Comment: I agree KHHMD12 needs a counter. Is there some reason the [i] terminal of the While Loop cannot be used as the counter? Why is the shift register needed?